# Oracle "create table as" null value

Tags: oracle

If you create an Oracle table using "create as" where one of your fields is null you will get the error:

> ORA-01723: zero-length columns are not allowed

Example query:

```
create table mytable as 
select 
    field_a, 
    null brand_new_field
from anothertable;
```

How can you get around this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Figured it out need to use `cast(null as datatype)`

```
create table mytable as 
select 
    field_a, 
    cast(null as varchar(1)) brand_new_field
from anothertable;
```

Some more info [here](http://dbaora.com/create-table-as-select-and-null-columns-views/).

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the way how to solve it.

```
create table mytable as 
select 
    field_a, 
    ' ' brand_new_field
from anothertable;
```